# Is there any tooltip option in the kendo-ui-angular2 charts?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there any tooltip option in the kendo-ui-angular2 charts or any other alternate to have it in the charts using angular2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tooltips are included in version `0.6` of the `@progress/kendo-angular-charts` package.

```
<kendo-chart>
  <kendo-chart-tooltip format="Tooltip content {0}">
  </kendo-chart-tooltip>
</kendo-chart>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, it worked for me. I downloaded the chart version npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-charts@0.6. But tooltips are appearing far away from the chart columns. If there is a way to show them closer to the columns then please let me know. 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please install 0.16 or later. Tool tip will be displayed closer.